# Is there any way to improve the tripping thrust ability of a Nimblewright?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, constructs, trip

Nimblewrights are intelligent constructs in the Monster Manual II that have the following ability:

> **Tripping Thrust (Ex):** A nimblewright's rapier-hand attacks are powerful enough to push over creatures its own size or smaller. An opponent who is the target of a successful critical hit from a nimblewright must make a Reflex save (DC 19) or be knocked prone as if tripped.

This looks exceptionally useful and piqued my interest, first because rapiers aren't normally tripping weapons, and second because this construct never actually makes a trip attempt. However, the second point makes it much harder to upgrade the construct's capacity to trip things. Are there any ways to upgrade or equip a Nimblewright to increase the DC for this reflex save?

Comment: Also, am I missing something, or is the construct that explicitly has two "rapier hands" not listed as being able to make separate attacks with each hand? Shouldn't their full attack routine involve two iterative attacks with the main hand and an additional offhand attack?

Comment: The format is a little weird; it does say “**Attacks:** 2 rapier-hands” and lacks a proper **Full-Attack** entry entirely, so I don’t think _Monster Manual II_ is denying them two attacks, it’s just failing to include that attack routine in the statblock.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, [Ability Focus](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsterFeats.htm#abilityFocus) will get you +2.

Beyond that, *Monster Manual II* doesn’t specify, but practically speaking, the save DC is almost-certainly calculated as 10 + ½ the nimblewright’s HD + the nimblewright’s Strength bonus. It might be Charisma-based, since the nimblewright has the same 19 in Charisma as in Strength, but that’s exceedingly unlikely considering the effect. Thus, additional HD, or improvements to the nimblewright’s Strength score, should improve the DC. If you aren’t the DM, though, you should talk to your DM about it, since it isn’t specified.

Taking things a step further, the nimblewright absurdly lacks Weapon Finesse. It would not be unreasonable for a nimblewright that got it to also use Dexterity for the trip attack DC instead of Strength. This has much less precedent in the rules, but it’s how I would rule things. That’s another +3 to the DC, along with attack bonus.

But I believe that’s it. There might be some really obscure options out there that provide very-generic bonuses to save DCs that would include the trip attack, but I’d be somewhat surprised.

The other thing you could theoretically do is take a page from a poisoner’s book, and seek out save-penalty auras. [Paladin of tyranny 3rd](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/variantCharacterClasses.htm#paladinofTyrannyClassFeatures) and [blackguard 3rd](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/prestigeClasses/blackguard.htm) each have one, though they probably don’t stack (they’re both “aura of despair”). Binder from *Tome of Magic* has two, as a matter of fact (aura of sadness at 3rd, aura of despair at 10th, with the Improved Binding feat), and one of them (aura of sadness) can even be gotten with the Bind Vestige and Improved Bind Vestige feats (sadly, that one is mind-affecting). Enlightened spirit 1st from *Complete Mage* has another (aura of menace), though anyone who hits the enlightened spirit becomes immune to it. One of the best out there is the hexblade 4th’s dark companion from the *Player’s Handbook II* ACF, since that can be moved independently of the hexblade, but a nimblewright will see little benefit from that. There are undoubtedly more such options.

Comment: Alright, so the optimal solution would be if your DM lets you use Pathfinder's rules for upgrading constructs to give it another five hit dice. But, assuming they say no, swapping Improved Disarm for Ability Focus is a given. Making both rapiers Feycraft then giving one Doom Burst and the other CurseSpewing should help. Equip Gloves of the Balanced Hand for the extra attack (two with haste). And put it where it can make as many attacks of opportunity per turn as possible. If we can't increase the DC normally then just flood the target in a number of critical hits until it fails a check.

Comment: @Benjamin RAW, feycraft does nothing for rapiers—that only allows you to use Dex for attack with light weapons, not with all weapons that are compatible with Weapon Finesse. For a rapier, a one-handed weapon, it just makes it compatible with Weapon Finesse—which of course it already is. I’m not sure about *gloves of the balanced hand* or *haste* because it already (maybe? per Question comments) has two attacks, and rapier-hands might (maybe?) be kinda-sorta natural-ish weapons? Anyway, really, I don’t think focusing on crits is a great play, really for anyone.

Comment: That is an excellent point about rapers and Feycraft not working together. I conflated two separate pieces of text.